# Android - Proper way to wait for handler object to be created

Tags: android

Folks,

Here is a simplified code for my background thread:

```
    public class MyThread extends Thread {
      private Handler _handler;

      public void run() {
         Looper.prepare();
         this._handler = new Handler();
         Looper.loop();
      }

      public void DoSomething() {
         if (!this.isAlive()) {
            this.start();
         }

         this._handler.post(blah);
      }
    }
```

The problem I have is that the background thread may not have yet created the handler object when post() call is made. Essentially, I need a wait loop for the handler object to be initialized. What is generated accepted method of doing this under Android?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Do you mean ".. created the handler object when *DoSomething()* call is made"?

Comment: Essentially yes. We not that handler object will not be created until start() is called (for the first time) from DoSomething(). But we need to wait until the bg thread starts running and handler object has been created. Current, I have a while loop where I sleep for 50 ms and check if handler has been created. I am wondering if there is a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a flag after you initialize the Handler and wait for this flag before calling `post`.

An easy way to wait for a flag in a concurrent system is with a `CountDownLatch`.  It would start at 1 and decrement after the Handler is initialized.  Check out the details here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html